# Initialize class scope member with method in StatelessWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have found a little issue while learning Flutter and I'm wondering which  is the better way to fix it.

Here is a very simple example code of the issue:

```
class SubWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() mainOnPressed;

  SubWidget(this.mainOnPressed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RaisedButton(onPressed: mainOnPressed,);

  void actionA() { /* Do A */ };
  void actionB() { /* Do B */ };
}


class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final SubWidget _subWidget;

  MainWidget() : _subWidget = SubWidget(_onSubPressed);

  Widget _buildChildA() => RaisedButton(onPressed: _subWidget.actionA,);
  Widget _buildChildB() => RaisedButton(onPressed: _subWidget.actionB,);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildChildA(),
        _buildChildB(),
        _subWidget,
      ]
    );
  }

  void _onSubPressed() { /* Do something */ }
}
```

The above code has an error, because I'm passing the *_onSubPressed* method as argument in the MainWidget constructor and it cannot be done because its initialization isn't complete.

I also can't move the initialization of *_subWidget* outside the constructor because it would give me an error because it's *final* and I can't remove the *final* because I'd get a warning for having a *non-final* member in an immutable class.

For the same reason, I can't defer the initialization of *mainOnPressed* in the *SubWidget* class.

I thought about moving the *_subWidget* member inside the *build()* method and pass it to the *_buildChildX()* methods, but while it is quite simple in this example, it would be more annoying having to do it with multiple members or methods that have the same issue.

Another solution I found is to move the *_subWidget* member and the two *_buildChildX()* inside the *build()* method like in the following code:

```
class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SubWidget _subWidget = SubWidget(_onSubPressed);
    Widget _buildChildA() => RaisedButton(onPressed: _subWidget.actionA,);
    Widget _buildChildB() => RaisedButton(onPressed: _subWidget.actionB,);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildChildA(),
        _buildChildB(),
        _subWidget,
      ]
    );
  }

  void _onSubPressed() { /* Do something */ }
}
```

While it works as expected, I am a little worried about the readability of the code with longer and more complex methods nested inside the build method.

Which is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do. You create everything as a field inside Main Widget?

Comment: I made the _buildChildX() methods to have a more modular and readable code, but also because in a real life scenario I may want to reuse those code. The _subWidget is a field inside MainWidget because I need to access it from the methods, so it needs to be in their scope.

Comment: That's not how you should do it in Flutter. You should extract these into other widgets

Comment: If I did understand what you mean, I don't think that this is always the case. For example in (at least) one of the samples by the flutter team, they wrote some methods to break the widget layout in a more readable way instead of writing a whole new widget. You can check the search and details screens in the veggieseasons sample.

Comment: These are very old samples. It is now considered anti-pattern and deprecated.

Comment: I don't think they're outdated, quite the opposite. The last commit on those file is from two month ago. However, assuming that I move the _buildChildX() methods to two new widget, I'd still need to give them a reference to _subWidget in order to call the actionA and actionB methods. How are you suggesting me to do it?

Comment: And more importantly, I need to pass SubWidget a reference to _onSubPressed

Comment: That there are recent commits doesn't mean this practice is not deprecated. Some examples on the flutter repo showing they are refactoring these: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/26722

Comment: Ok... thank you for the clarification. As I said I have just started coding in Flutter and I'm still trying to figure it out. I moved the two _buildChildX methods in different widget. At this point I'm moving the SubWidget inside the MainWidget build() method and I pass it to the ChildX constructor, am I right? Or is it better to declare a callback that than calls the actionX method through the MainWidget?

Comment: I don't understand that part. Why would you have `actionA` on `SubWidget` instead of `MainWidget`?

Comment: I'm going to make a stupid example. The SubWidget is a widget that can randomize its color and shape. The ChildA asks SubWidget to randomize its color. The ChildB asks SubWidget to randomize it shape. MainWidget should be notified if I click on the SubWidget. I am aware that in this case SubWidget should be a StatefulWidget. How would you solve this case? (PS: if you reply me as an answer I may be able to accept it)

Comment: Hum, again that's quite unrecommended. Widgets should _never_ obtain information from their children. In fact, it's rarely possible. You'll want to store these informations in the parent

Comment: So I should put the randomized state of SubWidget in any parent class that includes it, instead of having it only inside the state of the SubWidget itself? Also the parent itself is not getting the state of any of its children, but it's only defining 3 click listener and I think this is an allowed practice. Also I think it is allowed to have a click listener on the parent widget to interact with its children. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on far too many factors to answer. Do you mind showing a more concrete example of what you're trying? Because there's no generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the error "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used." on `MainWidget() : _subWidget = SubWidget(_onSubPressed());` is because `_onSubPressed()` may contain an unexpected expression. This is explained on the link provided in the error message: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#use_of_void_result

To solve this issue, you can move the function's contents to the constructor to initialize `_subWidget`.

```dart
final SubWidget _subWidget;

MainWidget() : _subWidget = SubWidget((){
  // Do something
});
```

Here's a complete sample that you can try out.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MainWidget());
}

class SubWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() mainOnPressed;

  SubWidget(this.mainOnPressed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('SubWidget'),
        onPressed: mainOnPressed,
      );

  void actionA() {
    /* Do A */
    debugPrint('Child A');
  }

  void actionB() {
    /* Do B */
    debugPrint('Child B');
  }
}

class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final SubWidget _subWidget;

  MainWidget() : _subWidget = SubWidget((){
    debugPrint('SubWidget');
  });

  Widget _buildChildA() => ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Child A'),
        onPressed: _subWidget.actionA,
      );
  Widget _buildChildB() => ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Child B'),
        onPressed: _subWidget.actionB,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            _buildChildA(),
            _buildChildB(),
            _subWidget,
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```